# react js how to align text to left while writing to csv and giving a bold header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am having difficulty adding styling to my CSV like aligning text to right and bolding the header.

below was the code I am using to push the data to CSV and providing the download to the export button.

```
const row = [
                    element.name,
                    element.data2,
                    element.data3,
                    element.data4,
                    '= "' + element.data5 + '"',
                    tarr[0],
                    tarr[1],
                    tarr[2],
                    tarr[3],
                    tarr[4],
                    tarr[5],
                    tarr[6],
                    tarr[7],
                    element.data6
                ];
                exportList.push(row)
            
        }); 
        
        let csvContent = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,';
        exportList.forEach(function (rowArray) {
            let row = rowArray.join(',');
            //let row = (rowArray.trim()).join(',');
            csvContent += row + '\r\n'
        });
        const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', encodedUri);
        link.setAttribute('download', 'my_data.csv');
        document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
        link.click() // This will download the data file named "my_data.csv".
    }
```

please kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't exactly style a CSV file. They are designed to be computer-readable, not human-readable. The best you could do is use bold UTF-8 characters for the header, but do note that this would make it extremely hard to read that file in a program later on. If you need styling, it is best not to use a CSV file.

I would recommend trying out this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-style. It uses xlsx files (Excel workbooks), which are designed to be human-readable and contain all the features you are looking for (and much more), but are less computer-readable.